# How to convert a Single Array into a multidimensional array in PHP using letters

Tags: php, arrays

I need to generate a multidimensional array based on a "map" of letters

my array :

```
$list = [
  0 => [
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'A'
  ],
  1 => [
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'AA'
  ],
  2 => [
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'AB'
  ],
  3 => [
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'B'
  ],
  4 => [
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'BA'
  ],
  5 => [
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'BAA'
  ],
];
```

but I need this:

```
$list = [
  0 => [
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'A',
    'childs' => [
      0 => [
        'name' => 'blah',
        'path' => 'AA'
      ],
      1 => [
        'name' => 'blah',
        'path' => 'AB'
      ],
    ]
  ],
  3 => [
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'B',
    'childs' => [
      0 => [
        'name' => 'blah',
        'path' => 'BA',
        'childs' => [
          0 => [
            'name' => 'blah',
            'path' => 'BAA'
          ],
        ]
      ],
    ]
  ],
];
```

I'm going to need this array to be in a way that is easy to manipulate, but I'm not able to use the "&" in a foreach so that I can generate an array at least close to what I put above.

sorry if i asked the question incorrectly... my english is bad and it's my first time here

Comment: what do you mean by "I'm not able to use the "&" in a foreach" ?

Comment: was trying to make array using "&" from php $item = &$item[$key]

Comment: `&` is for references. as i understand you just want to create a new array that is structured differently, with data copied over from the original array...

Comment: So you want to group by the `path` key which is a letter and the grouped items should start with that letter ?

Comment: yes , convert the letter path to array

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the `$list` giving each item a `['childs']` array then copy into a `$new_list` based on the path using the letters as keys in the array. I accomplish this below by constructing a string to evaluate with [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval).

```php
$new_list = [];
foreach( $list as $item ){
    $item['childs'] = [];
    $ev = '$new_list';
    foreach(str_split($item['path']) as $i => $p){
        if(0 == $i){
          $ev .= "['$p']"; // $new_list['A']
        }else{
            $ev .= "['childs']['$p']"; // $new_list['A']['childs']['A'] ... ['childs']['B'] etc.
        }
    }
    $ev .= ' = $item;'; // $new_list['A']['childs']['A'] = $item;
    eval($ev);
}

var_export($new_list);
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
array (
  'A' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'A',
    'childs' => 
    array (
      'A' => 
      array (
        'name' => 'blah',
        'path' => 'AA',
        'childs' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      'B' => 
      array (
        'name' => 'blah',
        'path' => 'AB',
        'childs' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'B' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'blah',
    'path' => 'B',
    'childs' => 
    array (
      'A' => 
      array (
        'name' => 'blah',
        'path' => 'BA',
        'childs' => 
        array (
          'A' => 
          array (
            'name' => 'blah',
            'path' => 'BAA',
            'childs' => 
            array (
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

See it in action here: https://onlinephp.io/c/cf8d0

### Note:

This works because you have all ancestor-items defined in `$list` **before** their descendants. If the order of items varies (like `'AAB'` before `'AA'`) then you will need to add some checks to see if the `$new_list['A']['childs']['A']['childs']` array exists yet and construct it when necessary.

Comment: Please explore a solution that does not require `eval()`. We cannot know how prone to user supplied data this snippet will be when used by developers in real projects.

Answer (score 0):

This recursive approach seeks out qualifying rows, pushes them as children of the desired parent row and unsets all rows that are used as children of a parent (somewhere).  The new array structure is not returned; the input array is modified by reference.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QS6Eu))

```
function rowsToTree(&$array, $parent = '') {
    $children = [];
    foreach ($array as $i => &$row) {
        if ($parent === substr($row['path'], 0, -1)) {
            // recurse for children
            $found = rowsToTree($array, $row['path']);
            // only declare the children element if has children
            if ($found) {
                $row['children'] = $found;
                // if not a top-level parent remove the row from the original array which has been pushed into the children element
                if ($parent) {
                    unset($array[$i]);
                }
            }
            // collect all children in this level for this parent (not top level) to be returned to 8ts parent then remove row from original array
            if ($parent) {
                $children[] = $row;
                unset($array[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $children;
}
rowsToTree($rows);
var_export($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-recursive approach that does provides the result in a new variable by sorting the array with deepest children first then using a nested loop to brute-force search for parents.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ctjlD))

```
$copy = $rows;
uasort($rows, fn($a, $b) => $b['path'] <=> $a['path']);
foreach ($rows as $i => $row1) {
    foreach ($rows as $j => &$row2) {
        if (substr($row1['path'], 0, -1) === $row2['path']) {
            $copy[$j]['children'][] = $row1;
            unset($copy[$i]);
        }
    }
}
    
var_export($copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
$list = [
    ['name' => 'blah1', 'path' => 'A'],
    ['name' => 'blah2', 'path' => 'AA'],
    ['name' => 'blah3', 'path' => 'AB'],
    ['name' => 'blah4', 'path' => 'B'],
    ['name' => 'blah5', 'path' => 'BA'],
    ['name' => 'blah5', 'path' => 'BB'],
    ['name' => 'blah6', 'path' => 'BAA'],
    ['name' => 'blah6', 'path' => 'BAB'],
    ['name' => 'blah6', 'path' => 'BAC'],
];


$data = [];
$arr = &$data;
foreach ($list as $item){

    $letters = str_split($item['path']);

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($letters as $letter){

        $path = substr($item['path'], 0, $i);

        if (!isset($arr[$path])){
            $arr[$path] = $item;
            $arr[$path]['childs'] = [];
        }

        $arr = &$arr[$path]['childs'];

        $i++;
    }

    $arr = &$data;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Because there weren't much clues on the question on how to actually do the desired grouping. I'll assume, based on the provided output sample, that the grouping will be based on the first letter found in the values where the key is `path`. The task will basically be solved using [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) built-in function:

> Iteratively reduce the array to a single value using a callback function. <sup>Source: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)</sup>

To maintain a performant solution, we'll index the resulting array based on the letters we found (the letters we'll group using them). Like so we will iterate over the `$list` array only **once**.

The trick here is to decide what to do at every iteration of the `array_reduce` function:

- When it's the first time we encounter a new letter, let's call that letter `$letter`, then we will construct an array (based on your output sample) where `$letter` is the key.
- Otherwise, if we have already the letter in the resulting array we will simply *merge* the `children` of the resulting array of the `$letter` key.

Using the letters as keys will drastically improve the solution's performance because we can simply say `$result[$letter]` and this will immediately return the array found on the `$letter` key (O(1)).

To illustrate, here's a code sample that should get the job done:

```php
$list = [
    ['name' => 'blah', 'path' => 'A'],
    ['name' => 'blah', 'path' => 'AA'],
    ['name' => 'blah', 'path' => 'AB'],
    ['name' => 'blah', 'path' => 'B'],
    ['name' => 'blah', 'path' => 'BA'],
    ['name' => 'blah', 'path' => 'BAA'],
];

$result = array_reduce($list, function ($a, $c) {
    $l = substr($c['path'], 0, 1);
    isset($a[$l])
        ? $a[$l]['children'][] = $c
        : $a[$l] = [
        'name' => $c['name'],
        'path' => $c['path'],
        'children' => []
    ];
    return $a;
}, []);
```

The `$result` array will have the letters as keys, if you need to remove those letters and use numerical keys, you may call

And I have made a [live demo](https://3v4l.org/fWsdc#v7.4.32) too.

Comment: `BAA` needs to be the child of `BA`.  This task is seeking a recursive (or stacking) approach, but your answer only provides processing to a limited depth.

Comment: @mickmackusa The question itself doesn't provide much details on how to group or the general structure of the expected input.

Comment: The question includes an exact desired result from the sample input array.

Comment: @mickmackusa my attempt is there, maybe I'll update it (maybe not).

Comment: My downvote is there, if your answer is edited to deliver the desired result, I'll remove it.

Comment: @mickmackusa absolutely, that's your choice which i respect. Anyway, personally, am not here seeking some points. It's just am busy to review and edit the answer in time. The benefits that someone (or me) can obtain are what's important in my opinion.